# whta is equle to excel count if equation in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I have a string column 'Code' and I would like to create the 'Overall' column as represented below to count the repetition/frequency of each item code column.

```
Code    Overall frequency 
  A     1
  B     2
  C     3
  B     2
  C     3
  D     1
  C     3
```

Comment: df[‘Overall frequency’] = df.groupby(‘Code’)[‘Code’].transform(‘count’)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `factorize`:

```
df['Overall'] = df['Code'].factorize()[0] +1



df.groupby('Code')['Code'].transform('count')
```

Comment: I'm trying to count the frequency for text items in the Code column, But factorize will just replace text item with a numerical equivalent whatever the count of the frequency.